# Getting SIGBART error on segue.

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I am getting `SIGBART` error when segue to a viewController is called.
The execution goes into this function and stops at `return` statement with error `SIGBART`.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([RS_AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

However, I don't see anything in console log. Nothing gets printed.

I have tried debugging and execution behaves well until it gets out of `prepareForSegue:` method. BTW, this method does not have any code in it.
I have tried deleting and creating a new segue.
I also checked that segue id name are same in code and storyboard.
I tried clean-build, and closing and opening an Xcode.

Any idea?

Comment: I just redid it to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode, go to the Breakpoint Navigator, and add All Exceptions. It will breakpoint at your code at where it finds an exception.

[image]

### Edit

When Xcode breakpoints at the line, press "Continue program execution", and the console should print out the exception. What does it say?

[image]

Comment: How to add `All Exceptions`. I don't find it.

Comment: Found it. Let me try running it.

Comment: It stops at this line : `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"createTrip" sender:self];` . But I already know that problem is with segueing. But don't know exactly what.

Comment: I am sure it prints nothing to console.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether or not yours UIViewController(self) is connected with your another UIViewController not from button, view or something, but exactly from view controller. And your segue is called "createTrip". UIViewController(self) is highlighted when you choose segue.

[image: storyboards]